# Is there an alternative to atof in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, atof

I am finding that `atof` is limited in the size of a string that it will parse.

Example:

```
float num = atof("49966.73");
cout << num;
```

shows 49966.7

```
num = atof("499966.73");
cout << num;
```

shows 499966

I need something that will parse the whole string accurately, to a floating point number, not just the first 6 characters.

Comment: Why do you think it is the input that is truncating? Have you considered the possibility that the input is accurate but the output is only 6 digits?

Comment: It's the opposite, `std::cout` doesn't print all of the digits. Try for example `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << num;`. Or your `atof`-implementation is utterly broken.

Comment: Use of double for the receiving value instead of float plus std::fixed of ios_base::std for fstream is returning an accurate result

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) from [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) standard library, as mentioned in the comments, still, there will be conversion issues due to lack of precision of `float` types, for better results use `double` and [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) for conversion:

```
float num = std::atof("499966.73");
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << num;
```

```
double num = std::stod("499966.73");
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << num;
```

[The first prints `499966.72`, the latter `499966.73`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q9OGzEWO8gp1O6xX).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. Use of double instead of float and std::: fixed , ios_base::fixed has solved the problem

Comment: @Deek880, I'm glad you solved it, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) if you feel it helped you.